# Função não continua após segunda execução na mesma classe

Tags: jquery, loop, plugin, slider

Bem, venho desenvolvendo um tipo de "slider de conteúdo" que troca o conteúdo de um certo `div ('.item .frase-test')` para o conteúdo do seguinte item na ordem dos `<span>`.

Consegui fazer tudo o que precisava que fosse feito até agora, porém um empecilho me segura de terminar tudo.

Após a execução uma vez do script na classe ativa no loop, o counter que fica em cada item não funciona, já tentei até utilizar indexes diferentes e tudo mais para cada um, mas nada feito...

Hospedei temporariamente aqui: http://badoc.com.br/labs/timer e como vocês podem ver, o *loop* continua, e as funções também estão de acordo, porém o círculo em volta não.

EDIT:

```js
$(function () {
  var spin = function() {      
    $('.btn-ativo').circleProgress({
      value: 1,
      size: 79,
      fill: { color: "#bfd432" },
      animation: { duration: 1000 }
    }).on('circle-animation-end', function (event) {
      $(this + 'canvas').fadeOut(300);
    });
  };
  $('.btn-item').on('click', function () {

    var btn = $('.btnss').parent();
    var self = this;
    var parent = $('.items').parent();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var mostrar = parent.find('.' + id);

    $('.btn-item.btn-ativo').removeClass('btn-ativo');
    $(this).addClass('btn-ativo');

    parent.find('.ativo').fadeOut(200, function () {
      $(this).removeClass('ativo');
    });
    $(parent).fadeIn(400, function () {
      $(this).addClass('ativo');
    });
    $(mostrar).addClass('ativo', 400);
  });

  setInterval(function () {
    $('.btnss').parent().find('.btn-item.btn-ativo').removeClass('btn-ativo').next().addClass('btn-ativo');

    if ($('.btn-item.btn-ativo').hasClass('last')) {
      $('#item').addClass('btn-ativo');
    }
    if ($('#item').hasClass('.btn-ativo')) {
      $('.item span').toggleClass('ativo');
    }
    $('.item').parent().find('.ativo').fadeOut(200, function () {
      $(this).removeClass('ativo');
    });
    $('.' + $('.btn-item.btn-ativo').data('id')).fadeIn(200, function () {
      $(this).addClass('ativo');
    });
    spin();
  }, 1000);

  $('.item').height($('.item span').height() + 60);
  spin();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top:40px;
}

.frase-test {
  background-color:#ccc;
  background-size:contain;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-position:center center;
  font-size:25px;
  position:relative;

}



.frase-test span {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:30px;
}

.ativo {
  display:block !important;
}


.user {
  position:relative;
}

.user-info {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.user-info span {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0 !important;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto 0;
}

.btn-group {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:30px !important;
}

.btn-ativo {
  pointer-events:none !important;
}

*:focus {
  outline:none !important;
}

.btn {
  background-color:transparent !important;
  border:none !important;
  position:absolute;
  margin-right:30px;

}

.btn span, .btn canvas {
  position:absolute;
  top:10;
  left:10;
}


.carre {
  width:79px;
  height:79px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}


.carre span {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:53px !important;
  position:absolute !important;
  top:15px;
  left:31px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:36px !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#000;
}

.btn-ativo span {
  color:#bfd432 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
<div class="container items">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <!-- ITEM 1 (ativo by default) -->
      <div class="item frase-test text-center">
        <span class="ativo item1">
          Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim.
        </span>
        <span class="item2">
          Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
        </span>
        <span class="item3">
          adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
        </span>
        <span class="item4">
          Mussum ipsum cacilds, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="item user">
        <div class="user-info">
          <span class="ativo text-center item1 test-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle center-block">
            <h3>John Doe</h3>
            Diretor Criativo
          </span>
          <span class="text-center item2 test-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle center-block">
            <h3>John Doe 2</h3>
            Diretor Criativo
          </span>
          <span class="text-center item3 test-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle center-block">
            <h3>John Doe 3</h3>
            Diretor Criativo
          </span>
          <span class="text-center item4 test-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle center-block">
            <h3>John Doe 4</h3>
            Diretor Criativo
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnss">
    <a id="item" data-id="item1" data-single="1" class="btn-item carre btn-ativo 1"><span>1</span></a>
    <a id="item" data-id="item2" data-single="2" class="btn-item carre 2"><span>2</span></a>
    <a id="item" data-id="item3" data-single="3" class="btn-item carre 3"><span>3</span></a>
    <a id="item" data-id="item4" data-single="4" class="btn-item carre 4"><span>4</span></a>
    <a id="item" class="btn-item carre last hidden"><span></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para o spinner, utilizo o seguinte plugin:
https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o código que já tem até o momento aqui.

Comment: Olá @LuisHenrique, primeiramente muito obrigado pela rápida resposta!

Irei atualizar em instantes o tópico original com os códigos, um instante por favor.

Comment: @Raphael, consegue editar a sua pergunta para adicionar um snippet que reproduza o seu problema?

Comment: Prontinho! Editado, obrigado pelas respostas amigos!

Comment: @Raphael, tentei editar o seu exemplo para que possa ser executado no proprio topico, verifique se está acontecendo o mesmo comportamento indesejado.

Comment: Obrigado Toby, sim, ocorre da mesma forma, o loop continua, mas o spinner não. E desculpe pela minha "noobisse" aqui, sempre utilizei para tirar dúvidas com perguntas já existentes porém nunca para fazer a minha própria hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o seu problema:

Ao concluir a animação do `spin` você não estava destruindo ele por completo, por isto acontecia este comportamento indesejado.

como o plugin não fornece um método destroy, você irá precisar remover o widget e apagar a instancia dele, para isto você pode ver o método spin com as modificações abaixo.

```
var spin = function() {  
    var widget = $('.btn-ativo').circleProgress({
        value: 1,
        size: 79,
        fill: { color: "#bfd432" },
        animation: { duration: 1000 }
    });
    widget.on('circle-animation-end', function (event) {          
        widget.circleProgress('widget').remove();
        widget.data('circle-progress', null);
    });
};
```

O segundo ponto, é o seu algoritmo para pegar o proximo btn-item, quando chegava ao ultimo elemento visivel, ele seleciona o proximo (hide) e o primeiro.

as alterações abaixo devem resolver.

```
var btItens = $('.btnss').parent().find('.btn-item');
var atual = btItens.filter('.btn-ativo');
var proximo = atual.next();
if (proximo.hasClass('last'))
    proximo = btItens.first();
atual.removeClass('btn-ativo');
proximo.addClass('btn-ativo');
```

Comment: Muitísismo obrigado Toby! A parte do loop está perfeita agora! Porém não sei se foi falta de atenção minha ou algo do tipo, mas após inserir o segundo código,os items ficam "pulando" forma randomica entre eles. E mais uma coisinha, mesmo o loop estando perfeito, após o clique em um anterior ou posterior, o script não continua após elemento tal qual fora clicado. Bom, é isso, agradeço de mais por tudo, depois me informe uma forma de te pagar uma cerveja! abraços!

Comment: Se possível, você poderia passar o código todo do JS de uma vez só? Só para eu comparar e ver se as edições que fiz foram no lugar certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Posso, mas não agora

Comment: Bom dia, sem problemas!